# Latest Pycharm saying "Interpeter seems invalid" for brew installed version

Tags: pycharm

Why would `pycharm 2019` not accept a brew installed version of python?

[image]

I am using that brew installation in both `intellij` and in `Pycharm 2018.3 Community Edition` as well as on the command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to reinstall *brew*'s python - following this: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/350012/55242

I did need to manually edit the `ipython` script to point to the brew installed version:

```
#!/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.3//bin/python3
#/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.7  # Remove this one
```

After this I was able to point a new `python sdk` to the brew installed 3.7.3:

[image]

And the new pycharm 2019.X *jupyter* support is .. *looking good* !

[image]